# Magento get product id on mini cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, mini-cart

How to get product id from product which already added to cart in mini cart ?

I've opened this file :

```
app/design/frontend/<theme_name>/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml
```

but I still not have idea to get product id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get product id in minicart

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$productId = $_item->getProduct()->getId();
```

Comment: You know you can mark it accepted ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can get all product data with **$product** variable.

   ```
   <?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>

      <?php 

           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
           ->load($_item->getProductId()); 

          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($product->getData());
          echo "</pre>";           

       ?>
   ```

Comment: thank you, look like I will need it when I want get others data

Answer (score 1):

You can get product data with `$product` variable using below code.

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
```

And you can get product id using `$product` variable like below.

```
$productId = $product->getId();
```